# Getting react router to work

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Trying to get the most basic routing working

```
var Router = ReactRouter;
var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
var Link = Router.Link;
var Route = Router.Route;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;



    var Hello = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return <div> 
            <h1> Hello at {this.props.now} </h1>
                              <RouteHandler />

            </div>
        }

    });


    ReactDOM.render(<Hello now = { new Date().toString()} />, 
        document.getElementById('outer-container'));

        var routes = (
    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={Hello}>

    </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function(Handler) {
    React.render(<Handler />, document.getElementById('outer-container'));
});
```

But I get the following error

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `Hello`.
```

What am I missing

Comment: what version of react-router are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.4.1

Comment: your code would work if you were using version 0.13.x, which is really old.

Comment: Thanks it works with 0.13.x, any examples on 2.4.1?

Comment: you got a tutorial here -> https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial